# Vertx Event Bus And Hazelcast Scaling

Tags: java, hazelcast, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-eventbus

I am using Vertx 4.4.5 in my project. I have created a few services and achieved a 3k TPS with 11 microservices on an 18 core VM running on Dell R730 with OS RHEL 9. Each request cycle has multiple read and writes on database as well as on Redis. Redis and Database are on the same machine but on different VM.

The message size was around 1kb when the TPS was 3k. Whereas, when I increase the message size to approx. 100kb which is to be considered an average production message size. The TPS dropped to 600. I checked the logs and found that event bus's consumer is getting the message after a few seconds delay. I googled and found that event bus is not designed for large messages so I used shared data to write my 100kb message on an async map and used the event bus to send the apiKey only for identification and fetching purpose. So, on my next service I fetch that data using that apiKey from the shared data map, asynchronously.

The problem is from service A (ApiGateWay) to B (BusinessService) I write all the 100kb in shared data and upon completion of writing the data on shared data

```
map.put(.., ..).onCompelete(res->{
if(res.succeed()){
   eventBus.request(.., .., ..);
}
});
```

I called the event buss using

```
eventBus.request(.., .., ..);
```

to send data to next service, whereas on the other service the consumer receives this message after the same delay which was before when I was using event bus and not shared data. I have also set the message buffer of consumer as well to 10k.

```
eventBus.consumer(.., ..).setMaxBufferedMessages(10000);
```

Am I missing something? Some other configs are:

> WorkerInstances on A -> 100 WorkerPoolSize on A -> 100
>
> WorkerInstances on B -> 100 WorkerPoolSize on B -> 100

I have also tried to scale hazelcast when starting service A and B using

```
 -Dhazelcast.socket.receive.buffer.size=10240 -Dhazelcast.socket.send.buffer.size=10240
```

Load Run Details

> - Jmeter
> - 7000 Threads
> - 100 loop count
> - 0.7s Ramp up
> - 1000ms Constant Delay

Thanks for your help in advance. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say with any certainty what might be happening, but what serialization method are you using for the Hazelcast map?  Java Serializable is very inefficient so if that is being used, changing that to something like Compact or IdentifiedDataSerializable could make a difference.

Comment: After my analysis I am getting on the conclusion that writing the data on sharedMap is actually slow. Because we are using routingContext.body().asString() and it doesn't take much time (a few microseconds maybe) as I have timestamped it. Whereas, sharedMap is taking almost 1.7seconds as per my timestamp in the logs. I am still investigating but this is what I am seeing so far.

Comment: I am although running all the services on the same system but this line from the vertx docs is depicting the same situation "Beware that the latency relative to asynchronous shared map operations can be much higher in clustered than in local mode" https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_using_the_shareddata_api